# Convert List of Maps to Stepper in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a simple todo list app using flutter. I would like to create a Stepper widget from a list of Maps as follows.

```
[
      { 
        'task': 'Cook for 5 min',
        'content': '30',
      },
      {
        'task': 'Stir gently',
        'content': '20',
      },
]
```

Currently I am doing this in my builder function :

```
List<Step> todoSteps = args['todos'].map<Step>((todo) {
      return Step(
        title: Text(todo['task']),
        content: Text(todo['content']),
        isActive: _currentStep >= i, // this is the issue
      );
    }).toList();
```

I then proceed to set the steps parameter of the Stepper widget with todoSteps.

This mostly works fine except the isActive parameter where I have to check if the _currentStep is less than index (i). But the issue is when I can't seem to get the index in function.

I tried using asMap() function on the list and then read the index but it always results in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.asMap().entries` should provide the what you need:

```
List<Step> todoSteps = args['todos'].asMap().entries.map<Step>((e) {
    var i = e.key;
    var todo = e.value;
    return Step(
      title: Text(todo['task']),
      content: Text(todo['content']),
      isActive: _currentStep >= i, // this is the issue
    );
  }).toList();
```